# AWS Amplify combine authorization rules

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-amplify

I have a multi tenant application in AWS Amplify, I'm using the Custom-attribute-based multi-tenancy described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/custom-attribute-based-multi-tenancy.html)

All models have a composite key with "company" being the unique tenant ID, and the cognito user pool has a custom attribute `custom:company` which links the user to the tenant data.

Example type below:

```
type Customer @model
    @key(fields: ["company", "id"])
    @auth(rules: [
         { allow: owner, ownerField: "company", identityClaim: "custom:company"},
         { allow: groups, groups: ["Member"], operations: [read] },
         { allow: groups, groups: ["Admin"]},
    ])
{
  company: ID!
  id: ID!
  ...
}
```

I want to add user groups to cognito to manage the operations that different users can perform - e.g. `Admin` users can perform all operations, but `Member` users can only perform `read`

The problem is the first `owner` auth rule will match for anyone with the matching `custom:company` attribute, regardless of their Group.

Is there a way to combine owner and group `@auth` rules - i.e. both `owner and groups` needs to pass to have access to an item?

For example - users of the `Member` group is allowed but only when their `custom:company` attribute matches the `company` of the model

Another example - anyone with a matching `custom:company` attribute have access to an item but `Members` can only read

Comment: I am interested in this as well.  Have you come up with a workable solution with Amplify?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this is currently not possible with the AWS Amplify directives.

You cannot combine tenant based auth with role based auth to get a fully multi-role-multi-tenant app.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-category-api/issues/449

You could opt for a lambda authorizer and then handle all the auth logic yourself in there. But that will be tedious.